# removing an object from Publication database sys.sp_droparticle and sp_dropsubscription

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replication, database-replication, merge-replication

SQL Server Admin is not my forte. So please bear with while I explain this 
A `SQL Server 2012 cluster` is involved in a `Change data capture ( CDC )` effort using a 3rd party `CDC` utility. for it to work replication needs to be turned on, without replication `CDC` will not work.  The `CDC` taps some 2000+ odd tables from `SQL Server` in a database Db1. Out of these we found out that some 200+ tables undergo `truncate` and `load` as against  increments. So we removed those from our CDC lists but since replication is turned on at DB Level we also need to remove these from `publication database` so that truncates happening to this exception list wont need `replication` switched off DB level ( aka truncates to these tables and `replication` can co-exist. As its known, for truncates to happen we need to switch off replication. The code is in prod so replacing `truncate` by `delete` is not an option now besides the fact that for billion row tables deletes are going to be expensive & time consuming ) 
The above is the requirement. So based on that if a better solution can be conceived do let me know

**What I tried :**

```
EXEC sys.sp_droparticle @publication = 'pub', @article = 'art', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1
```

**Error I get**

```
Msg 14013, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_droparticle, Line 104 [Batch Start Line 2]
This database is not enabled for publication.
```

**Another SP**

```
DECLARE @subscriber AS sysname;

EXEC sp_dropsubscription @publication = 'AR_PUBLICATION_00010', @article = 'BPA_BRGR_RUL_GRP_R' ,@subscriber=@subscriber

Msg 14013, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_dropsubscription, Line 55 [Batch Start Line 1]
This database is not enabled for publication.
```

But using `GUI` I am able to uncheck the tables I dont want in that `publication`.   ( right click publication --> properties --> articles --> check /uncheck whatever you want excluded ) . I dont have any `subscription` just there is a publication. 

Whatever code I ran through GUI above I can def.  run through T-SQL But I dont know what code was it that was run ? How do I get this done using a scripting approach. I have 200+ tables to deal with and unchecking em 1 by 1 ain't helping

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407937/how-to-configure-replication-this-database-is-not-enabled-for-publication

Comment: Well I used this code via GUI from trace `exec sp_droparticle @publication = N'AR_PUBLICATION_00010', @article = N'AR_ARTICLE_00010_915143397', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1` there are 2 issues here 1 )  the actual table name is not the article name. How do I do a mapping or how can I use the actual table name not the internal name  as param 2 ) the changes are NOT saved.  If I refresh all those articles come back again . Am I missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly four years late, but in case it helps anyone... I think you want `sp_dropmergearticle` not `sp_droparticle`.

```
EXEC sys.sp_dropmergearticle @publication = 'pub', @article = 'art', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1
```

I was getting an identical error message using `sp_droparticle`, but `sp_dropmergearticle` removed the table from the publication and allowed me to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

> Whatever code I ran through GUI above I can def. run through T-SQL But I dont know what code was it that was run ? How do I get this done using a scripting approach.

SSMS does not have a special API.  Everything it does, it does through TSQL.  So use SQL Profiler to watch what SSMS does, and capture the script.

Comment: Well I used this code via GUI from trace `exec sp_droparticle @publication = N'AR_PUBLICATION_00010', @article = N'AR_ARTICLE_00010_915143397', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1` there are 2 issues here 1 )  the actual table name is not the article name. How do I do a mapping or how can I use the actual table name not the internal name  as param 2 ) the changes are NOT saved.  If I refresh all those articles come back again . Am I missing something